# Back button in Android like in Gmail app?

Tags: java, android, gmail, android-actionbar

In Android ICS and JellyBean, the native Gmail app has a Back button "<" right by the Gmail icon when not in the startscreen/inbox. Is there a way I could integrate this in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's part of the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) component. Take a look at the [Navigating up](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Up) section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) if your target is API Level 11 and higher. 
Otherwise I recommend you to use the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which is compatible to most of the devices in the market.

Comment: I am using the ActionBar but when I start a new Activity, the "<" button doesn't show up. Is there a method I have to call that enables that?